# JQuery source file is missing from my test site?

Tags: jquery

I have tested the following code on [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/); however, when I tried it on my local machine it does not work. I have a feeling that the cause is that I do not have the file jquery.js. I  was thinking  that it was  only part of the jquery script declaration and no more. What is written in jquery.js? Is there an alternative file I can include?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you must have jquery.js or load remote file: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js, see here: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Which will load the jQuery library from google CDN(Content Delivery Network). There are several other CDN, check the list here http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Or

Load https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js in browser and save the file as `jquery.js` in the directory where your above file is and your code will work fine.

Check this tutorial for more details http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: thanks i have checked and works fine,just one note:it does not need save link as a seperate  .js file,i have directly included in src tag

Comment: Yeah You dont need to download the file, But you need your own local copy of jQuery sometimes when you are not connected to Internet. In that case the CDN link wont load and you wont be able to run your project locally. Just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools is linking to the common javascript library known as [jquery](http://jquery.com/). You need to either download and store it locally to your site so you can reference it, or you can use the gooole api version: [ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is up to you and your situation (production or development?). I assume you would want the production version because it is usually smaller which means it will load quicker.

Comment: i will use it instead of downloading